# Is it possible to load native video content ads using DFP network?

Tags: android, admob, google-dfp, google-ad-manager

I am getting **error code 3 (No fill)** while requesting native video ads from DFP and success from AdMob using Unified Native Ads on android. 
This article https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/7031536?hl=en specifies that video ads are also available as UnifiedNativeAds.

While requesting video ad using AdMob's AdUnit ID I am able to get video ads successfully but on the other hand, creating video native ads on DFP and using that AdUnit ID I am getting no fill every time.

I have learnt about VAST IMA ads, but my use case involves showing ads that are **NOT** integrated as pre-roll or post-roll or as simple video ads.

I want the logo, title, CTA, description info with the video ad, as a UnifiedNativeAd object.  How to solve this use-case?